# Django: Getting single element from related manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have an app where a user can "vote" on a "post". In the UI (template) I'd like to indicate whether the user has already voted. That would require doing something like this (which doesn't work). Is there a legal way to do this in the template (without re-writing the views)?

I'm trying to get all users who have voted on a post. This clearly doesn't work or make sense really, but hopefully it can communicate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{% if user in post.post_votes.all.the_user %}
```

Relevant parts of the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)

class Vote(models.Model):
    the_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="post_votes")
    the_post = models.ForeignKey("Post", related_name="post_votes")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass user to the queryset filter. But there is no way to do that with built-in template syntax. So you should [create your own](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

```
# app.templatetags.app_tags
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def has_voted(user, post):
    return post.votes.filter(the_user=user).exists()

# template
{% load app_tags %}

{% if user|has_voted:post %}
   <b>Already voted</b>
{% endif %}
```

Alternativly, you can loop over queryset of votes but that's not a good idea.

Comment: The brilliance of this answer shines like a thousand suns. Thank you!!

Comment: it's always a pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Within `Vote`'s field `the_user`, `related_name` is defined as `post_votes`. What I would try first is fix this is the template (there you used `post.votes....` instead of `post.post_votes....`.

As for the main problem, I would build a method within `Post` entity to return all voters - something like:

```
@property
def voters(self):
    votes = self.post_votes.all()
    return set([vote.the_user for vote in votes])
```

After this, I could simply use: `{% if user in post.voters %}` in template.